# Работа Python без выделения окна консоли

Tags: python-3.x, события, клавиатура

Есть код, который проверяет события клавиатуры, но он работает только тогда, когда "Выделена" (нажато на окно) консоль. Т.е. при компиляции без открытия окна, она в принципе не работает. Должно быть так, чтобы пользователь нажимал клавиши не обязательно при "выделенной" консоли, и эти события проверялись. Как мне это реализовать?

Заранее благодарен.

===========================================================================

code:

```
import msvcrt as kb
import os

try:
    os.chdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop')

filetxt = open('logs.txt','w').close()
filetxt = open('logs.txt','a')

while True:
    try:
        key = chr(ord(kb.getch()))
        if key == ']':
            filetxt.close()
            break
        filetxt.write(key)
    except:
        pass
```

Запускаю, когда нажимаю на консоль и что-то пишу (кроме  ']'), всё вписывается в файл logs.txt (после нажатия на ']'). Но, когда я переключаюсь на браузер, что-то пишу в нём, затем нажимаю на ']', код никак не реагирует. Даже после нажатия на консоль и затем только ']', консоль закрывается, а в файле logs.txt - пусто, значит скрипт не работал, когда я находился в браузере.

Comment: Опубликуйте свой пример.

Comment: Исправил вопрос